# how to save an edited image from qgraphicsview in QT

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am writing codes to load in image from a file and did some edits on this image(change some pixels' value), zoomed in or zoomed out and then save the image. I tried to use qgraphicview and qgraphicsscene to save the image. However, when I tried to save the image, it always save the visible region of the scene. My purpose is to save the edited image in original resolution. Below are my codes.
Loading part:

```
void ImageViewer::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        image = new QImage(fileName);
        if (image->isNull()) {
            QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Image Viewer"),
                tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(fileName));
            return;
        }
        qgraphicsscene = myqgraphicsview->getScene();
        qgraphicsscene->setSceneRect(image->rect());
        myqgraphicsview->setScene(qgraphicsscene);
        qgraphicsscene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
        currentName = fileName;
    }
}
```

Saving part:

```
QPixmap pixMap = QPixmap::grabWidget(myqgraphicsview);
    pixMap.save(fileName);
```

I think the problem may be in saving part. I tried to find a method in QGraphicsScene that can extract image from it, but failed. Can someone help with that? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The scene knows nothing about images. The `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that you create in `addPixmap` - does. Alas, you have your `image` member, that you presumably use in subsequent image editing operations. Just save that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addPixmap` method returns a `QGraphicsPixmapItem*`. You need to remember it, and use it to save the pixmap. For example:

```
class ImageViewer {
  QGraphicsView * m_view;
  QString m_currentName;
  QGraphicsPixmapItem * m_item;
  ...
};

ImageViewer::ImageViewer() : m_item(nullptr) { ... }

void ImageViewer::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
  if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;
  QImage image(fileName);
  if (image.isNull()) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Image Viewer"),
      tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(fileName));
    return;
  }
  QGraphicsScene * scene = m_view->scene();
  scene->setSceneRect(image->rect());
  m_item = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
  m_currentName = fileName;
}

void ImageViewer::save()
{
  if (!m_item) return;
  QSaveFile file(m_currentName);
  if (! file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Unbuffered)) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Image Viewer"),
      tr("Cannot save %1.").arg(m_currentName));
    return;
  }
  QImage const image = m_item->pixmap().toImage();
  image.save(&file);
  file.commit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, I tried to edit the scene, and I want to save the edited result. In this method, I can only save the original image. How can I save the edited image.     `code`scene->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0,
   QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));`code`

Comment: @ivory Ah, it seems there's no such thing as an edited image. The `addEllipse` calls actually create graphical primitives that overlap your original image. You'd need to manually render the graphics scene at the correct zoom to reconstruct the "image". You're not doing any editing at all, just overlaying of primitives, each of them individually drawn. If you keep "editing" the image for too long, you'll notice that things get really, really slow. All those ellipses stay in memory, and each full scene refresh has to redraw them.